# How to create a pop-up in pygame with transparent background and how to control loop as a line is been drawn?

Tags: python, pygame

```
def timer_initial_state(screen):
    '''Creates an thin line representing the timer'''
    pygame.draw.line(screen,
                     COLOR_ORANGE_RED,
                     (0,screen.get_height()*0.35),
                     (screen.get_width(), screen.get_height()*0.35),
                     3)

def timing_sequence(screen):
    '''Creates a timer in the form of a line'''
    increment = 0.01
    while increment >=0:
        pygame.draw.line(
            screen,
            COLOR_BUTTON_UP,
            (screen.get_width()*increment, screen.get_height()*0.35),
            (0, screen.get_height()*0.35),
            3)
        pygame.draw.line(
            screen,
            COLOR_ORANGE_RED,
            (0, screen.get_height()*0.35),
            (screen.get_width(),screen.get_height()*0.35),
            3)
        increment += 0.01
```

The first function draws the line. The goal of the second is to draw over the first line in at a specific interval like that of a clock. ie. it should draw over a portion of the line after 1 second.

What I want to do looks just like this:

[image: screenshot]

Furthermore, I want to show a popup after the timer is done with a transparent background.

Comment: For starters, your `timing_sequence()` function is an infinite loop. Try changing it to `while increment < 1.0:`.

Comment: @martineau did that. any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will progressively draw a line:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30  # frames per second
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

class ProgressiveLine(object):
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, color=WHITE, width=1):
        self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2 = x1, y1, x2, y2
        self.color, self.width = color, width
        self.dx = self.x2-self.x1
        self.dy = self.y2-self.y1

    def draw(self, surface, percentage):
        percentage = min(abs(percentage), 1.0)
        xcur = self.x1 + self.dx*percentage
        ycur = self.y1 + self.dy*percentage
        pygame.draw.line(surface, self.color, (self.x1, self.y1), (xcur, ycur),
                         self.width)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,400), 0, 32)
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    prgrsline = ProgressiveLine(10, 390, 490, 10, RED, 3)

    percent_complete = 0.0
    while True:  # display update loop
        screen.fill(WHITE)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        if percent_complete < 1.0:
            percent_complete += 0.01
        prgrsline.draw(screen, percent_complete)

        pygame.display.update()
        fpsclock.tick(FPS)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As martineau said you need to fix your loop so it will complete.
2. You are drawing your partial line first, then drawing the full line over it.  You need to draw the order of on top last.
3. You also need to flip (or update) the display after your draw.
4. This should all be done inside an event loops so your app will still responding to events.
5. Timing based on per frames is a bit ugly. I would have a number of seconds for animation and a start time and compute the `increment = (now - start_time) / animation_time`

maybe it would be better to have this just be a function that draws based on time and not have its own while loop.

Comment: The doc on display.flip() updates the entire screen. I also draw the whole line before drawing part of the line This is what i do:  I do now:
`def timing_sequence(screen):
 '''Creates a timer in the form of a line'''
 increment = 0.1
 lengthOfLine = 0.1
 while increment <1.0:
  timer = pygame.draw.rect(screen,COLOR_BUTTON_UP,(screen.get_width(),screen.get_height()*0.35,screen.get_width()*lengthOfLine,screen.get_height()*0.35),3)
  increment += 0.1
  lengthOfLine += 0.1
  screen.blit(screen,timer)  `

Comment: @JamesDelaliTorkornoo you flip after each state that you want to draw?  I dont see it anywhere in your while loop in the function `timing_sequence`.  In the while loop the COLOR_BUTTON_UP line is part of the line, it is immediately covered with COLOR_ORANGE_RED

Comment: `while True:
 ... mouse evnts are here shortened...
 screen.fill(COLOR_BACKGROUND)
 show_definition(screen)
 show_score_and_round(screen)
 timer_initial_state(screen)
 timing_sequence(screen)
 show_mute_button(screen,15,screen.get_height() - 16 - 60)
 CLICK_STATUS = show_mute_button(screen,15,screen.get_height() - 16 - 60)`

Comment: @JamesDelaliTorkornoo you never get to the main loop untill the whole thing is over.  You are looping in your `timing_sequence` loop

Comment: what loop do you suggest I use then?

Comment: I would probably have your progress bar be a object that; keeps track of start time, how long the progress bar will take, and accept draw request with current time. I'd leave the looping to the main loop unless you have a really good reason for breaking it out.  (like a totally different game state)

Comment: Sounds great. But incase I want to create it as a method, do you think using the main loop is safe?

Comment: @JamesDelaliTorkornoo for something as simple as a progress bar using the main event loop makes sense.  I'm not sure what you mean by "safe"